# Unable to find solution - showing error in this way - "Attempted import error: 'date-fns' does not contain a default export (imported as 'dateFns')."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs.
I want to create a calendar which accepts an event for a particular date.
A small example can be found [here](https://medium.com/@w.difulvio523/create-a-custom-hooks-calendar-in-react-e50bbba456e1)

However, when I want to see the output, it outputs `Attempted import error: 'date-fns' does not contain a default export (imported as 'dateFns')`.

Can anyone assist me here to resolve the error?

After importing in this way - **import addMonths from 'date-fns/addMonths***

I'm getting error as shown in snapshot. [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEZSf.png)

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: could you share a code snippet? It looks like you didn't npm install date-fns though

Comment: @mlisonek - Hi, Here is the code - "https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-gould-bx4lw"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the date-fns documentation, the api has been updated since this article was written.

Rather than a single default export

`import dateFns from "date-fns";`

You want to import each of the functions used individually.

so for...

```
const nextMonth = () => {
   setCurrentDate(dateFns.addMonths(currentDate, 1));
}
const prevMonth = () => {
   setCurrentDate(dateFns.subMonths(currentDate, 1));
}
```

You would need to import each function idnividually

```
import addMonths from 'date-fns/addMonths'
import subMonths from 'date-fns/subMonths'
```

Then change the implementation to remove the `dateFns` object. So...

```
const nextMonth = () => {
   setCurrentDate(addMonths(currentDate, 1));
}
const prevMonth = () => {
   setCurrentDate(subMonths(currentDate, 1));
}
```

Here are the date-fns docs https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/Getting-Started

Comment: Hi, after writing in this form - it is showing errors.

Comment: You are going to have to share the errors with us. What does the error say?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated a snapshot in my query. Could you preview the query once?

Comment: You should read the error, errors often tell you exactly what you need to fix. In this case, it says `onDateClick` requires more arguments but you are only giving it one. You've got this. If you share more errors, share the whole thing, your screenshots cuts half of the error.

Answer (score 1):

try this way.

```
import { subMonths, addMonths } from "date-fns";
```